# Asynchronous Triggers in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm looking to implement some "Asynchronous Triggers" in Azure SQL Database. There was [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766761/asynchronous-triggers-in-sql-server-2005-2008) that asked this same question with pretty much the same needs as mine but for SQL Server 2005/2008. The answer was to use the Service Broker. And it's a great answer that would serve my needs perfectly if it was supported in Azure SQL Databases, but it's not.

My specific need is that we have a fairly small set of inputs selected and stored by a user. A couple of those inputs are identifications of specific algorithms and some aggregate-level data all into a single record of a single table. Once saved, we want a trigger to execute those selected algorithms and process the aggregate-level data to break it down into tens of thousands of records into a few different tables. This 2-8 seconds to process, depending on the algorithms. (I'm sure I could optimize this a bit more but I don't think I can get this faster than 2-5 seconds just because of the logic that must be built into it.)

I am not interested in installing SQL Server inside a VM in Azure - I specifically want to continue using Azure SQL Database for many reasons I'm not going to get into in this post.

So my question is: **Is there a good/obvious way to do this in Azure SQL Database alone?** I can't think of one. The most obvious options that I can see are either not inside Azure SQL Database or are non-starters:

1. Use real triggers and not asynchronous triggers, but that's a problem because it takes many seconds for these triggers to process as it crunches numbers based on the stored inputs.
2. Use a poor-man's queueing system in the database (i.e. a new table that is treated as a queue and insert records into it as messages) and poll that from an external/outside source (Functions or Web Jobs or something). I'd really like to avoid this because of the added complexity and effort. But frankly, this is what I'm leaning towards if I can't get a better idea from the smart people here!

**Thanks for the help!**

---

*(I am posting this here and not on DBA.StackExchange because this is more of an architectural problem than a database problem. You may disagree but because my current best option involves non-database development and the above question I referenced that was almost perfect for me was also located here, I chose to post here instead of there.)*

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to do *directly* in Azure SQL Database, but there are a few options:

As @gotqn mentioned in a comment, you can use [Azure Automation/Runbooks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-runbook-management/); [applied to Azure SQL specifically](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/).

You can also check out [database jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-jobs-overview).

Answer (score 0):

You can use LogicApps. It has a SQL connector that implements an asynchronous trigger...

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/